# data member tracking owning class's `this` across when copied

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class with a data member that keeps track of the outer `this` as its owner. What I want to do is keep track of the new `owner` after being copied constructed.

```
class MyType;

struct Member {
  MyType* owner;
  Member(MyType* m) : owner{m} {} // store pointer to owner
};

struct MyType {
    Member mem;
    MyType() : mem(this) { } // I am my member's owner
};

int main() {
  MyType a;
  MyType b(a);
  assert(b.mem.owner == &b); // fail.
}
```

Of course I could write the `MyType(const MyType&);` constructor and set the new pointer, but the real class this is in is huge and writing the constructors will introduce a maintenance problem. If I can constrain it (even introducing another intermediate class/wrapper) I'd be much happier.

The real-world case is a `unique_ptr` member with a Deleter that references the owning `this`, so really I only *need* move operations. So far everything I've thought of has been pretty half-baked.

Comment: Can'y you just add a data member to `MyType`, whose sole job would be to transfer the ownership in it's move or copy constructors? And then those would be simply called by implicitly defined (I assume you have these given your second-to-last paragraph) constructors of `MyType`?

Comment: @Rostislav I'm not sure what you're imagining, that seems like it would suffer from the same problem

Comment: Well, I'd say there's not enough information in your question. You say you can't add copy constructor. Can you add a data member that wouldn't require you to add one? Or you would have to edit 20 other constructors to initialize it properly?

Comment: @Rostislav yes I can add another data member

Comment: I was thinking about one thing, but then my brain switched to another (it's 3AM here after all :)). But my original thought is still there. The only thing it would need is to change all accesses such as `b.mem` to `b->mem`. Is it also problematic?

Comment: I mean something like [this](http://rextester.com/VTII23371). (just edited the link with annotations about what changed compared to your code)

Comment: Unfortunately overloading `operator.` is not possible (at least [yet](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4173.pdf))

Comment: @Rostislav this doesn't work. You have the one issue of `mem(std::move(mem))` initializing using itself, but once inside the OwnerTransferer move constructor body you're initializing `mem.owner` with `this->owner`, the latter of which is never initialized.

Comment: Yeah. 3AM. Brainfreeze. Good luck!

Comment: Last [thing](http://rextester.com/HYJT13508), I promise. But it's butt-ugly, works only if the `OwnerTransferrer` is the first member of `MyType` _and_ if `MyType` is standard layout. You probably thought of something like this, and it is probably not of much value, but who knows, maybe it's of _some_ value?

Comment: unfortunately the real MyType isn't standard layout :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new class to handle the ownership change.  Rename your existing MyType to MyTypeImpl (Member is unchanged) and create a new MyType derived from that:

```
struct Member {
    MyType* owner;
    Member(MyType* m) : owner{m} {} // store pointer to owner
};

struct MyTypeImpl {
    Member mem;
protected:
    // protected constructor to disallow creating instances of this class
    MyTypeImpl(MyType *pThis) : mem(pThis) { } // I am my member's owner
};

struct MyType: public MyTypeImpl {
    MyType(): MyTypeImpl(this) { }
    MyType(const MyType &r): MyTypeImpl(r) { mem.owner = this; }
    MyType(MyType &&r): MyTypeImpl(std::forward(r)) { mem.owner = this; }
    // etc
};
```

A variation would be for Member to point to MyTypeImpl instead of MyType (then MyTypeImpl would be unchanged from what you posted except for the rename).

Comment: @Rostislav ...which got renamed, and the default copy/move constructors etc for the renamed class are still auto generated (so OP doesn't have to write those).

Comment: You still have `MyType(const MyType &r)` don't you?

Comment: @Rostislav Yes, but "the real class this is in is huge and writing the constructors will introduce a maintenance problem" - the maintenance problem is deferred into MyTypeImpl and isn't in MyType anymore.

Comment: Well, OP has more information on this. Let's hope that your solution works. We're here to try and help other people after all.

Comment: s/std::forward/std::move. This works with additional normal stuff throw on top of it (inheriting constructors, protected `~MyTypeImpl()`)

Answer (score 1):

First a little dangerous solution:

```
class MyType;

struct Member {
  std::ptrdiff_t ownerOffset;
  Member(MyType* m, Member MyType::* p) : 
    ownerOffset{ reinterpret_cast<char*>(m) 
    - reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) } // store offset to owner
  { assert( &(m->*p) == this ); } // make sure it is our owner
  MyType* getOwner() {        
    return reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(
      reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + ownerOffset);
  }
};

struct MyType {
    int x; //some offset
    Member mem;
    MyType() : mem(this, &MyType::mem) { } // I am my member's owner
};

int main() {
  MyType a;
  MyType b(a); 
  assert(b.mem.getOwner() == &b); // ok.
}
```

But this will not work for some exotic classes, like when you virtual inherit MyType (as you cannot cast pointer to member to virtual base class).
Such cases needs to manually update each member, for now I cannot find any automatic solution.